# Could not catch posted data in my routes.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, express

express application. I am posting  data via ajax . Bu i could not catch data from my route. Here is my ajax :

```
function Confirme(commentid,status){
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Management/Comment/Confirm/',
                type: "POST",
                data: {"id": commentid,"status": status}

            })
```

I am sending commentid(345345345) and status(0) to this function. (Tried in firebug also). And here is my routing codes:

```
app.post('/Management/Comment/Confirm/',function(req, res){
    if(!req.session.email){
        return res.render(__dirname+"../../../views/management/accessdenied.jade",{
        title: 'Dont have permission',
        stylesheet: 'accessdenied',
        error: 'You are not authorized to access this page'
        });
    }
    console.log('Is id correct:' +req.params.id);
    Comment.findByIdAndUpdate( req.params.id, {"status": 1}, function(err, result) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        console.log("result:"+result);
        Comment.find({},function(err, comments){
            console.log("comments: "+comments)
            if(! comments.length) {
                console.log('no comment');
            }

            return res.render(__dirname+"/views/commentindex",{
            title: 'comment list',
            stylesheet: 'commentindex',
            comments:comments
            });

        }); 
    });

});
```

But this code is always return me to undefined:

```
console.log(req.params.id);
```

I checked in firebug. I think may be i could not send data to my ajax function. But not. Here is the firebug:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use either [`req.body.id`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.body) or [`req.param('id')`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.param).

[`req.params`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.params) contains named parameters in your route URL. For instance:

```
app.post('/post/:id', ...);
                ^^^ this can be read using `req.params.id`
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to write `req.body.id` .
for POST resquest its req.body.paramsName and for GET request its `req.query.paramsName`

Comment: For `GET` it's `req.query.paramsName`.